# When and When Not to Deploy "ex" = "from"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In Comments to cmw's answer, https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4130/1982, Joonas asked whether,

> "fames ex inopia sequitur",

is preferable to,

> "fames inopiam sequitur".

The suggestion, from cmw, was that a new verb e.g. "nasci" would be required, giving,

> "fames ex inopia nascitur", =

> "hunger arises from poverty".

What's the difference? Why is "ex" = "from" appropriate with "nasci" and not "sequi"?

In Q: [To get over a trauma OR just learn to live with it](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/21309/1982), I asked whether in:

> "vidua dixit unum annum consumpsisse convalescere ex morte mariti,"

should it be, "ex morte", "morte" or did it not matter?

Any thoughts on the use of "ex" = "from" in these two examples?

Comment: It was more of a gut feeling than a statement of rule (thus the language used), but I can try to find some examples for you later.